# How can I use C# To read low-level SMART log files (host specific)?

Tags: c#, windows

I've got some VERY brief notes on the commands to get the device identity data block, and grab the log file data.
My aim is to read the raw log data for the bytes contained in the "host specific" data.

**Main commands**

Identify device : ECh - This returns the device details in a 256 bytes block.

SMART Read log : D5h - This returns a 256 byte block of log data.

Log address for host specific data is 80h to 9Fh, (address 128 to 159, 31 bytes long)

There's 16 log pages.

**-----------------**

I've found WMI commands and examples that read out SMART values, but none that read the log files.

This area appears to be smack in the middle of data that none of the examples try to access. =(

In C# is there a way to issue an "Identify device" command, (EC), and read back the block of 256 bytes?
From there I can have a go at issuing a "Read log" command (D5) - but I don't have notes on how to select the log page. Perhaps they're all returned in the 256 byte block?

Many thanks for your help!

This is for a tiny freeware open source project for cine-operators. Having never accessed SMART data, I couldn't find any extended poking around in SMART log's... or recognise an example if I fell over it!

=D

Comment: Just to clarify... are these commands... commands you'd run in a command prompt?

Comment: Hi Davey, no not a command prompt. They're hexadecimal device commands sent to the hard disk controller... I know C# has <unsafe> directive for pointers and other memory tasks. 
The bit I need to learn is the ways and means of talking to the disc, if at all possible. It may be via Windows only - through WMI, and if that's the case I suspect all the bits I want are stripped out as being "too unspecific" to be useful.

Comment: You probably want to add an introductory paragraph explaining what SMART is (maybe with a link to an overview and to the API). You probably also want to change the title so that people who know what you are talking about will recognize your question (and maybe find some tags)